# Can't use assume role to accesss aws eks which is created by assume role api

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I created a aws eks using assume role api. Role A assume role B to performe create EKS api. I create the eks and specify that the EKS's cluster role is role C. As I know,the role C's arn will be stored in eks aws-auth configMap.

When A assume role C to access the created EKS, "Failed to get namespaces: Unauthorized" returned.

I always use assume role to invoke API. Does anyone know, whether aws-auth store role C's arn like 'arn:aws:iam::C:role/k8s-cluster-role' or eks store the role arn in aws-auth in another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some misconception; The role that is stored in **aws-auth configmap for system:masters group** in your cluster is not the cluster role, but the iam principal that creates the cluster itself, [as per official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html#:%7E:text=When%20you%20create%20an%20Amazon%20EKS%20cluster%2C%20the%20IAM%20principal%20that%20creates%20the%20cluster%20is%20automatically%20granted%20system%3Amasters%20permissions%20in%20the%20cluster%27s%20role%2Dbased%20access%20control%20(RBAC)%20configuration%20in%20the%20Amazon%20EKS%20control%20plane.).

> When you create an Amazon EKS cluster, the IAM principal that creates the cluster is automatically granted system:masters permissions in the cluster's role-based access control (RBAC) configuration in the Amazon EKS control plane.

From what you have written, if the sequence is right, and that assume-role approach you are following works properly, **you should be able to query your cluster api resources with role-b not role-c**, since b is the one you used to create the cluster. In your current setup, you are expecting role C to be able to access cluster resources, though you created with role b.

Comment: You are correct.